# WSO2 ESB HTTP Endpoint does not get added to the Synapse configuration

Tags: wso2-esb

I have built an ESB Project with an HTTP endpoint. But for some reasons. The Endpoint that I have defined and added to the ESB Solution does not seem to be reflected in the project and seem to be not reflecting when I deploy to the server.  The endpoint is basically not being used. I have also tried to check the under the Defined Endpoints tab in the server Enterprise Integrator console, @ 
Home     > Manage    > Service Bus   > Endpoints
but it isn't there. Numerous restarts have not helped neither has undeploying and redeploying the car file. Can someone point out where I might have gone wrong? As usual, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Could be different things, to check:

- Extract the .car file (it's just a .zip, so rename or use 7zip to
  extract) and see if your endpoint is there.
- Check if the serverrole in the pom file is correct (should be EnterpriseIntegrator it think)
- Sometimes renaming artifacts causes problems as the file does not get renamed correctly or a reference is not updated in one of the
  project files. Try removing the endpoint and use 'search in files' to
  remove any lingering references in pom files.

Comment: Hi Jan, I did according to your first advice, I found the EndPoint was not included in the CAR file I have since added it to the pom file if the CAR project. It was successful.